# How to use Mongo Database URI in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I am new to MongoDb, i am using it in eclipse Birt Report but i am not getting what is Mongo Database URI in this.???

How to use it.??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either fill in the "Server", "Host" etc options otherwise available or just post a URI in the form of:

```
 mongodb://[user]:[password]@[hostname]:[port]/[database]
```

Various driver documentation samples have examples of this. For example the Java driver:

http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html

Comment: Thanks for it @ Neil Lunn. Can u provide me the link or any documentation about generating BIRT report using MongoDb. i am completely new to it.